# Broken Client Integration in Extranet Scenario

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication, word

**Scenario:** SharePoint Foundation 2013 Extranet with "Anonymous Access" and "Client Integration" turned on. Users authenticate by FBA. Server ist secured over SSL (with URL-Rewrite-module active) and reachable over the internet.

**Problem:** Users are not able to open word files residing on the SharePoint directly in the client application as I would in an intranet domain-based scenario.

**Error messages:**

> "There has been a network or file permission error. The network
>   connection may be lost"

and simple

> "Cannot open file"

**Info:** I'm aware that Office has its own authentication and is not simply grabbing the credentials from Internet Explorer, where I am able to authenticate just fine. But Word should ask me for credentials, shouldn't it? It doesn't matter if I use Office 2010 or 2013 and if I put the website address on the "Intranet" List in Internet Explorer. I also made checks on "Remember me" when logging in to the website with no success.

**Question:** Is it even possible to enable Client Integration in that scenario?